# Draw a polyline between cuncerent location and a locked location

Tags: android, google-maps, location, draw, polyline

I'm having a problem here. I have Google maps with my own location and with a locked location now the locked location is no problem but the current location is. I want to draw a line between these 2 locations. They both work so there is no problem. The only problem is here:

**Polyline code**

```
 Polyline line = googleMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
    .add(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()), 
         new LatLng(52.01936, 4.39113))
    .width(5)
    .color(Color.RED));
```

so my idea is to get these 2 linked with each other, but I don't know what to put in the:

```
.add(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude())
```

this is my code for showing my CURRENT location coordinates as a TextView:

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    TextView tvLocation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_location);

    // Getting latitude of the current location
    double latitude = location.getLatitude();

    // Getting longitude of the current location
    double longitude = location.getLongitude();

    // Creating a LatLng object for the current location
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

    // Showing the current location in Google Map
    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

    // Zoom in the Google Map
    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));

    // Setting latitude and longitude in the TextView tv_location
    tvLocation.setText("Latitude:" +  latitude  + ", Longitude:"+ longitude );
```

Any one have a idea how I can get this working? if it's not clear enough for you tell me then I explain it more clearly.

Comment: What's the problem? What's wrong with `.add(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude())`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to extract the location value from `onLocationChanged` to a Class Variable. For example :

`public Location curLoc = new Location();`

Then inside your `onLocationChanged()`, pass the value of `location` into `curLoc`, like this : `curLoc=location`

Then on your Polyline, use `curLoc.getLatitude()` and `curLoc.getLongitude()`

I hope this is helpful, good luck ^^

Comment: I don't know, he did not write the full code. And in my analysis, he's confused because the `location` inside polyline is not updated with his current location

Comment: sorry guys for a late reaction i fixed the problem now the only thing i had to add was this: `public Location lastLocation; `haha stupid that i didn't know this

Comment: @reidzeibel true i still need to keep my polyline updated with my current location, it only updates the polyline if i fully close the app, but i gues i just have to put the polyline code inside my `onLocationChanged` function or/and make a `onResume` function